# C# LinkedListNode reference after calling Remove on LinkedList

Tags: c#, reference, linked-list

**My question:** Hi, does method- LinkedList.Remove(LinkedListNode n) changing references of others elements in LinkedList?

*Application is little bit complex so atleast I will try to explain how I got here, but maybe It will be confusing*

> I have a program which storing references(LinkedListNodes from
>   LinkedList) into another iterable class. And in some point,
>   application starts deleting these LinkedListNodes with
>   method-Remove(LinkedListNode node) and also delete this element from
>   my class which stores these references. It runs good for a while, but
>   in some point It will loose one of the reference in my class and I get
>   null reference(in myNode) when i want to call
>   LinkeList.AddAfter(myNode, value) with error: “The LinkedList node
>   does not belong to current LinkedList”.

**EDIT:**

I was translating notes, etc...
So I am using BinarySearchTree for quick search, LinkedList for normal iterating and QUEUE for deleting old elements.

This is insert in my Tree class:

```
 public Node Insert(DictionaryPair dictionaryPair, LinkedList<DictionaryPair> dictionary)
    {
        Node currentNode = nodeRoot;
        while (true)
        {
            if (currentNode == null)    //if i inserting 1st element
            {
                nodeRoot = new Node();   //creating node(root)
                dictionary.AddFirst(dictionaryPair);    //inserting into Linked list on 1st place
                nodeRoot.dictionaryNode = dictionary.First;  //and taking a reference
                return nodeRoot;  //end while
            }
            else if (currentNode.dictionaryNode.Value.CompareTo(dictionaryPair) >= 0)
            {   //sending element into left
                if (currentNode.left == null)   // and is empty
                {
                    currentNode.left = new Node();  //creating new node
                    currentNode.left.myParent = currentNode;    //reference to parent
                    currentNode.left.dictionaryNode = dictionary.AddBefore(currentNode.dictionaryNode, dictionaryPair);
                    //and inserting into dictionary (Before) current node and save the refence on it to left
                    return currentNode.left;  //end while
                }
                else
                {   //or shift to left
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;
                }
            }
            else
            {   //sending element into right
                if (currentNode.right == null)   // is null
                {
                    currentNode.right = new Node();  //create new node
                    currentNode.right.myParent = currentNode;   //reference on parent
                    currentNode.right.dictionaryNode = dictionary.AddAfter(currentNode.dictionaryNode, dictionaryPair);
                    //and insert into dictionary (After) current node and save  the refence on it to right
                    return currentNode.right;  //endwhile
                }
                else
                {   //or shift to right side
                    currentNode = currentNode.right;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

class Node:

```
    public LinkedListNode<DictionaryPair> dictionaryNode;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node myParent;
```

I can call delete method on my Node:

```
public LinkedListNode<DictionaryPair> DeleteMe()
    { 
        LinkedListNode<DictionaryPair> deletedNode = this.dictionaryNode;
        if (this.left == null && this.right == null)
        {   //Delete leaf
            if(myParent.left == this)
            {
                myParent.left = null;
            }
            else // else if(myParent.right == this)
            {
                myParent.right = null;
            }
        }
        else if (this.left != null && this.right == null)
        {
            this.right = this.left.right;
            this.dictionaryNode = this.left.dictionaryNode;
            this.left = this.left.left;               

        }
        else if (this.left == null && this.right != null)
        {
            this.left = this.right.left;                
            this.dictionaryNode = this.right.dictionaryNode;
            this.right = this.right.right;
        }
        else
        {   //on left and right are tries
            Node currentNode = this.left; //throught the left side
            bool oneCycle = false;  //possibility of not iterating once thought the left side into the right (so it would be left)
            while (currentNode.right != null)
            {    //searching element most to the right
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
                oneCycle = true;
            }
            if (currentNode.left == null)
            {   //i am leaf
                if (oneCycle)
                {
                    currentNode.myParent.right = null;   //deleting refence on me
                    this.dictionaryNode = currentNode.dictionaryNode;   //and change a value
                }
                else
                {
                    currentNode.myParent.left = null;   //deleting refence on me
                    this.dictionaryNode = currentNode.dictionaryNode;   //and change a value
                }
            }
            else
            {   //im not leaf
                if (oneCycle)
                {
                    currentNode.myParent.right = currentNode.left;  //change refence on my tree
                    this.dictionaryNode = currentNode.dictionaryNode;   //and change value
                }
                else
                {
                    currentNode.myParent.left = currentNode.left;  //change refence on my tree
                    this.dictionaryNode = currentNode.dictionaryNode;   //and change value
                }
            }             
        }
        return deletedNode;
    }
```

This is my main class for working with the arrays MyDictionary, whichs have

```
    private LinkedList<DictionaryPair> data;    //for iterating search
    private Tree binarySearchTree;  //for quick search
    private Queue<Node> queue;   //references on added nodes 
    //in binarySearchTree... they are ready to be deleted
    private int maxCount;
    private bool maxCountReached;
```

When I am inserting into MyDictionary, I calling this method

```
public void Insert(DictionaryPair input)
    {
        if (!maxCountReached)
        {
            if (queue.Count() >= maxCount)
            {
                maxCountReached = true;
            }
        }
        if (maxCountReached)
        {
            data.Remove(queue.Dequeue().DeleteMe());
        }
        queue.Enqueue(binarySearchTree.Insert(input, data));
    }
```

Comment: include a minimal, complete code example with your question, so we can see what you're doing and what the problem might be. "runs good for a while" is often an indicator of parallelity gone wrong, or a flaw in the algorithm.

Comment: Your question is very vague and your application description is inadequate for others to help you. For instance, by "elements" are you talking about "nodes" or something else maybe broader? Obviously, the references that `node.Previous`, `node.Next`, `list.First`, and `list.Last` might all change when you remove a node. It sounds like your problem is this other iterable class or how your application uses it at least..

Answer (score 1):

> [...] does method LinkedList.Remove(LinkedListNode n) change references of other[s] elements in LinkedList?

When we look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,352) of the `LinkedList.Remove` method, we find that the framework does not mess with other elements except for adjusting their `prev` and `next` pointers (in order to close the gap caused by the removal, and as per definition of the linked list principle).

Except for the border cases, it is simply

```
node.next.prev = node.prev;
node.prev.next = node.next;
```

The object (`item` in the internal data structure) of other elemenst is not modified by the `Remove` operation. The object targeted by the `Remove` operation itself is also not directly affected. As the node is detached from the list, it becomes eligible for garbage collection if no other living objects keep a reference.

The exception you see is [generated here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,379):

```
if ( node.list != this) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.ExternalLinkedListNode));
}
```

If this validation fails in `AddAfter`, it can mean that:

- Calling code is attempting to reference an existing node that is not attached to any `LinkedList` at all, for example a node that was previously removed from the list. In the code you posted, this would be `currentNode.dictionaryNode` and I'd **focus on lines where this is assigned when debugging**
- Calling code is attempting to reference an existing node that belongs to another instance of `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake in implementation of DeleteMe method in my BinarySearchTree. I didnt change parents reference of nodes which was under a found currentNode. But thank you for help. Have a great day...